# When using styled-components, how can I merge my style with the existing css on the element?

Tags: css, styled-components, css-transforms

I am attempting to style a component with `transform: translateX(...);` css property. However, the existing component already uses `transform: translate();`, so my style is simply overwriting the existing `transform` property. What I would like to do is read the existing translate data on the element so I can simply add my translate amount to what is already there. My ideal solution would look something like this:

```
const Element = ...

const StyledElement = styled(Element)`
  transform: translateX(${currentTranslate.x - 5});
`
```

The question is, **How can I read the existing style from the underlying component?**

###### My Specific Use Case

(for those interested)

The element I'm styling is a Tooltip from reactstrap, which is positioned using `transform: translate(...position of target);`. I'm trying to make the tooltip bounce a little to give it some life, so I'm using:

This code to add animation

```
const horizontalDoubleBounce = keyframes`
  0% {
      left: 0;
  }

  20% {
      left: -5px;
  }

  40% {
      left: 0;
  }

  60% {
      left: -5px;
  }

  80% {
      left: 0;
  }

  100% {
      left: 0;
  }
`

const SpotlightTooltip = styled(Tooltip)`
  animation: ${horizontalDoubleBounce} 1000ms ease-in infinite;
`
```

I resorted to using the `left` property which is working because it doesn't override anything, but I would rather use `transform: translate()` for a smoother animation.

Comment: You need to add a ref attribute to the element in your JSX, read from there the style and pass it to the styled component. You can pass props to the styled component... I would add a more detailed example with code but i cant right now, so check styled components docs for more info. But thats the general approach to this

Answer (score 0):

You have to read `currentTranslate` outside of component and pass it's value as a prop to your styled component.

```
const Element = (props) => {
 const currentTranslate = window.scrollY // for example
 // ...

 return <StyledElement currentTranslate={currentTranslate}>
}
```

Styled component will be look:

```
const StyledElement = styled(Element)`
  transform: ${({currentTranslate}) => `translateX(${currentTranslate - 5})`};
`
```